# How can I use pipe sign or $ sign in quote in bash linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to substitute &|$ with comma in csv file. How can I do it using bash?

Comment: With bash only or can you use `sed`, `awk`, etc.?

Comment: ...though one certainly _could_ do it with bash only, if one chose...

Comment: BTW, in the future, it would be good to show what you tried yourself so we know the technical problem you encountered when solving this on your own.

Comment: Do you have quoted instances of the delimiter in the file?`"first$field"$"second$field"`, for example? Presumably, that should become `first$field,second$field`, not `first,field,second,field`.

Comment: @chepner, ...fair point; I'd honestly reach for the Python CSV module instead of implementing in shell at all if one wanted to convert arbitrary other delimiters while honoring quoting rules.

Comment: _ in csv file_ : Since in a csv file, the comma by definition is a field separator, are you sure that you want to create additional fields in each line?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, in pure `bash`

```
$: x='&|$'
$: echo ${x//[&|$]/,}
,,,
```

If you want the whole string converted to a single comma,

```
$: echo ${x//'&|$'/,}
,
```

If you want any consecutive set of those characters converted to a single comma...

```
$: shopt -s extglob; echo ${x//+([&|$])/,}
,
```

Processing a whole file can use a read loop to parse each line, or something more all-at-once, with some caveats - the read loop is generally safer. Be careful with your quoting either way.

```
$: shopt -s extglob; x="$(<x)"; printf "%s\n" "$x" "***" "${x//'&|$'/,}"
&|$
foo
&|$
bar
&|$
baz
&|$
***
,
foo
,
bar
,
baz
,
```

But generally, I'd use something like `sed`

```
$: sed -E 's/\&\|\$/,/g' x # every occurrence of this exact sequence
,
foo
,
bar
,
baz
,
```

or `awk`

```
$: awk '{gsub("[&|$]+",",")}1' x # any consecutive combination of these characters
,
foo
,
bar
,
baz
,
```

In the simplest case, if you are merely trying to convert the dollar sign and encountering difficulties because of various metacharacters, @Hasturkun's suggestion of `tr` is excellent.

```
$: echo '&|$foo
> &|$bar
> &|$baz
> ' | tr '$' ,
&|,foo
&|,bar
&|,baz
```

Comment: I'd just use `tr`, i.e `tr '&|$' ','`. You can also pass `-s` if you want to squash duplicates.

Comment: Very true, if each is individually relevant. Not sure it would work if the delimiter were a multicharacter string, but I think that's an unlikely case here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use perl for this.

```
perl -pe 's/\|/,/g' file.txt
```

That's substitute

`\|`  Pipe (or $ or &) with a backslash to 'protect' it

`,`   Replace with comma

`g`   Globally

Answer (score 0):

In pure bash, no tools not built into the shell itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ - run this with _bash_, not sh

while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "${line//[&$|]/,}"
done <in.csv >out.csv
```